# Computing a Probability with the Poisson Process.

Tags: sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

**NOTE: The questions can answered independently, but it is preferable to follow through the reasoning.**

Suppose $\{N_t\}$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda=4$. I want to compute 
$$\mathbb{P}[N_{10}=3\mid N_{15}-N_5=3].$$
Now we have the following equality of events 
$$\{N_{10}=3\text{ and }N_{15}-N_5=3 \}=\{N_{10}=3\text{ and }N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5\}.$$

> **First Question:** Is the event $\{N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5\}$ measurable w.r.t $\sigma(N_{15}-N_{10})?$

If the answer to the above question is yes, then the events $\{N_{10}=3\}$ and 
$\{N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5\}$ are independent and thus
$$\mathbb{P}[N_{10}=3\text{ and }N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5]=\mathbb P[N_{10}=3]\cdot\mathbb P[N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5].$$

Now the random variables $N_5$ and $N_{15}-N_{10}$ are independent and therefore 
\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}[N_{15}-N_{10}=N_5]&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}[N_{15}-N_{10}=n]\cdot
 [N_5=n]=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}[N_5=n]^2\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{20^k}{k!}e^{-20}\right)^2?\end{align*}

> **Second Question:** Is there a "nice" formula for computing $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{20^k}{k!}e^{-20}\right)^2$?

If yes then we can now get the probability of our original event by using that 
$$  \mathbb{P}[N_{10}=3\mid N_{15}-N_5=3]=\frac{\Bbb P[N_{10}=3]}{\Bbb P[N_{15}-N_5=3]}\cdot\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Bbb P[N_5=n]^2.$$

> **Third Question:** Is there a straighforward intuitive way of computing the probability of the original even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to calculate: $$P\left(N_{10}=3,N_{15}-N_{5}=3\right)$$ so
that on base of that you can calculate: $$P\left(N_{10}=3\mid N_{15}-N_{5}=3\right)=P\left(N_{10}=3,N_{15}-N_{5}=3\right)/P\left(N_{15}-N_{5}=3\right)$$
you should go for:

$$P\left(N_{10}=3,N_{15}-N_{5}=3\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3}P\left(N_{5}=k,N_{10}-N_{5}=3-k,N_{15}-N_{10}=k\right)$$
where $N_{5},N_{10}-N_{5},N_{15}-N_{10}$ are iid $\sim\mathsf{Poisson}\left(5\lambda=20\right)$.

The answer to your first question is: "no".

If it would be true then $1_{N_{15}-N_{10}=N_{5}}$ would be a function that can be written as $f(N_{15}-N_{10})$ which means that the value it takes only depends on the values that are taken by $N_{15}$ and $N_{10}$. That is evidently not the case: it also depends on the value taken by $N_5$.